# Managing node modules in npm5

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm still using  `node v6` and `npm v3` and planning to move to `node v8` and `npm v5`

I use `npm`  in `client(Angular2)` and `server side(Express)`

These are the steps  i follow to manage node modules in

## npm v3

#### to save in package.json and update npm-shrinkwrap.json

- `npm install packagename@version --save`

---

#### to save in package.json dependency and not to update npm-shrinkwrap.json

- `npm install packagename@version --save-dev`

---

- `npm install` will install dependency and dependencies but will not update `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file
- `npm run build` builds front end code using webpack
- `npm prune --production` removes all devDependencies  after the build process and will not update `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file

What i'm facing in

## npm 5.4.2

- `npm install` installs modules and  updates`package-lock.json` with dependency and devDependencies if any change in version
- `npm run build` builds front end code using webpack
- `npm prune --production` removes all devDependencies  from `node_modules` and  `package-lock.json`

---

1. #### How we can enforce keeping dependency alone in `package-lock.json` ?
2. #### Any other recommendations on build process ?
3. #### Should we keep devDependencies in node_modules if its not used in production?

---

### ------ Update on 10/25/2017 -------

To remove `devDependencies` without updating `package-lock.json`

try  **`npm prune --production --no-package-lock`**

Comment: As long as `devDependencies` isn't committed with your version control, that's fine. The `package-lock.json` is intended to replace the `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file with a slightly different format, but the file is used to keep track of what actually _is_ in the `node_modules` directory, rather than what _should_ be in the directory, which you seem to be hung up on a little.

Comment: as long as the deploy process for production uses `npm install --production` it won't matter that devDeps are in `package-lock,json`, they still shouldn't be installed

Comment: Step is more like
`npm install` , `npm run build` and then `npm prune --production` so `package-lock.json` is going to update two times

Comment: As of now i'm  using `npm prune --no-package-lock` to remove all `deveDependencies` without updating `packagae-lock.json`